# Gitignore man directory of an R package?

Tags: r, git, r-package

Because each and every file in the `man/` directory of an R package is automatically written with package **roxygen2**, I wonder what would prevent me from adding the entire directory to my `.gitignore`.

In other words, why all R packages on GitHub still version the `man/` directory?

Comment: Because you can't compile a package without `/man`. Yes, you can roxygenize the docs, but that's another step. Hopefully this will one day become modus operandi for building R packages. `roxygen2` will have to come a long way, though.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik You mean that `devtools::install_github` won't work?

Comment: Of course any wrapper can be made around `R CMD build`, but that's not the point. :) Technically you are correct, you can omit `/man` and count on the user to run `roxygenize` prior to compiling and installing the package.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the `git` tag since this is not a question related to git, but solely to R. You'd have the same problem in any other VCS, so it's not `git` specific at all.

Comment: @gucce I talk about GitHub and .gitignore in my question.

Comment: I can see that. But with that argument in mind you'd also have to add a `GitHub` tag. I found this question because I can help people with Git. However, I don't see how any knowledge about Git (or GitHub for that matter) could help you with this specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a convenience to users who use `devtools::install_github()`.

If `man/*.Rd` is not in the repo, they will get a note like `No man pages found in package...` upon install and later, `help(...)` or `?...` or `??...` will fail for your users with `No documentation` or `No results found`.

Comment: Are you sure of this? Can you see any example?

Comment: I experienced one recently when installing an R package of mine freshly on both Debian and macOS. If you want to test: `devtools::install_github("TIBHannover/BacDiveR", ref = "9252b807e08cc2e825f152d79c64d095c052da93"); library("BacDiveR"); ?retrieve_data` => as described above.

Comment: But if you try the [next `ref` (`b336e61c`)](https://github.com/TIBHannover/BacDiveR/commits/master?before=b336e61c31a71c8aac7e86dda274117edb8552d2+35), the help page appears.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the man directory to be present but not the files generated in it, place a .gitignore file in the man directory. This will force git to generate the directory, but still ignore the files generated.